# How to get a reference to the last returned object in Emacs Slime

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, slime

Using Emacs Slime, how can I access the object or value that was returned by the last expression in the REPL?

In ipython it's `_` so that I can save it in a variable if the return value is what I expected.

Is there something similar for Slime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common Lisp defines some variables which are bound the previous form and their values. These are:

- [`*`, `**`, `***`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v__stst_.htm) The most recent primary values.
- [`/`, `//`, `///`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_sl_sls.htm) The most recent values (each of these is a list).
- [`+`, `++`, `+++`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pl_plp.htm) The most recent forms.

These variables are bound each time a form is evaluated in the REPL (which is what Slime is doing). `*`, `/`, and `+` are bound the previous primary value, values and form. `**`, `//`, and `++` are bound to the previous values of `*`, `/`, `//`. `***`, `///`, and `+++` are bound the previous values of `**`, `//`, `++`.

Functions in Lisp may return more than one value; thus the difference between `*` which holds the primary (first) value and `/` which holds a list of all values.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to verdammelts answer, you can also copy and paste objects from the repl. For an example see the third image in [this](http://malisper.me/2015/07/14/debugging-lisp-part-2-inspecting/) article (that I wrote). For more information you should look at the [presentations](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Presentations.html) section of the Slime manual.